# why is this object-fit cover not working?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-maps, frontend

[image]

As you can see I'm not able to use object-fit to cover the whole  so, there's any other possible way for me to display this map in a way that the quality does not suffer so much?
here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="w-full h-full">
    <img
      v-if="staticImageSrc === ''"
      :src="require('@/assets/img/map-placeholder.jpeg')"
      class="object-cover"
    />
    <img v-else :src="staticImageSrc" class="object-cover" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: All the width but maintain proportions

Comment: @TomasGilAmoedo What do you think object-fit property does? Control dimensions of image? A quick visit to mdn would solve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the image's CSS to `width: 100%` rather than `width: auto` like you currently have it.

As shown in your inspector screen shot the `width: auto` is an inline style. So you may need to hunt for the cause of that, since the `<template>` you have posted in your question does not show a `style=""` attribute on this element. But it is evidently getting set somehow as evidenced by the dev tools.

[image]

The class which is setting it to `width: 100%` called `w-full` is getting overridden by the inline style.